# using php insert huge amount of data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to generate random strings and insert into database, the insertion should be efficient and robust. I have a generating strings function working like this:

```
public function getRandString(){
    $string= //generats a random string
    return $string;
}
```

db connection:

```
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
or die ( " Not able to connect to server ");
mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

Now I want to create a method that insert the random strings into database 1 millon rows at once with each row contains 2 column of random strings, how should I go about this?

thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I am a beginer in php, so I don't know whether I should use prepared statement or raw query....what do you suggest?

Comment: Just use a 'normal' query, there is no security hazard in this

Comment: but using prepared statement should be faster??? I have googled preparaed statment, it seems they are not reusing the statement.

Comment: If you're a beginner, I would recommend reading up on PDO. It's a much better way to communicate with databases in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: 1 million rows is not very much. I can't imagine you would spend much time waiting either way.

Comment: actually, I am not waiting, this is my first time writing such things, so I don't have a fast way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Use php to create a sql file to import via the command line, phpmyadmin, sequelpro, tomcat, etc

   - open a file
   - append the `INSERT INTO whatever VALUES ( 'randomshit', 'randomshit' );` however many times you want
   - close the file, use it to populate the db
2. Use the connection you mentioned above:

   - create the `INSERT INTO whatever VALUES( 'randomshit', 'randomshit' );` in batches of 25000

     ```
     $howMany = 40;
     // do this 40 times (40x25000 ) = 1,000,000
     while( --$howmany ) {
       $random = "";
       $randomMany = 25000;
       while( --$randomMany ) {
         $random += sprintf( "INSERT INTO whatever VALUES ('%s', '%s'); ", rand_text(), rand_text() );
       }
       // you'll now have a big list (25000 ) of insert queries to insert
       mysql_query( $random );
     }
     ```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off creating your random string function database-side and running an `INSERT ... SELECT` query once to generate your rows.

Answer (score 0):

We can combine two tricks to generate a table of junk:

Create a table of single digits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/273703/260007

```
CREATE TABLE num (i int);
INSERT INTO num (i) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);
```

Generate random strings:

```
INSERT INTO junktable
SELECT
  (SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6)) AS aa,
  (SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6)) AS bb
FROM       num AS l1
INNER JOIN num AS l2
INNER JOIN num AS l3
INNER JOIN num AS l4
INNER JOIN num AS l5
INNER JOIN num AS l6
LIMIT 100; -- number of wanted rows
```