# MySQL Query bring back those not in a list

Tags: mysql

EDIT: What I need to show are those emails from the list in the SQL query that **DO NOT** appear in tresp.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM tresp WHERE email IN ('[email addy here]','[email addy here]','
[email addy here]','[email addy here]','[email addy here]')
```

This may sound odd but want I want to do is actually show the email addresses that are **NOT** in the tresp - is that possible?

Cheers,

H.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show emails from tresp that aren't in the list or emails in the list that aren't in tresp?

Comment: The latter - email in the list that are not in tresp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricky question, this solution isn't very elegant but it works;

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'email1' AS email UNION 
  SELECT 'email2'          UNION 
  SELECT 'email3'          UNION 
  SELECT 'email4'          UNION 
  SELECT 'email5' 
) AS a WHERE a.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM tresp);
```

[If you run into the same charset problems I had, create the table with default charset utf-8.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32613)

Edit: Added an AS since older MySQL seems to have trouble without it.

Demo at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b41ac/1).

Comment: This only works if you can pre-process your 'email' list and know its length, but in that case it would work - and maybe it's the only way

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') a WHERE a.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM tresp)' at line 227

Comment: @josh.trow I assume you'd generate the `SELECT xx UNION' part the same way as you'd generate the entries for IN, generating it in code from a list. And no, I can't really think of another way if the list needs to be a part of the query and not in a table.

Comment: @Homer_J I don't get an error when just copy/pasting it in. What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Gotta love when someone else posts the same answer while writing it out!  I coujldn't think of a more elegant way to do it either to be honest.  Was torn between a left join or subquery for checking tresp

Answer (score 5):

So... you want `NOT IN` then?

```
SELECT *  
FROM tresp  
WHERE email NOT IN ('[email addy here]','[email addy here]')
```

Or do you want the email addresses?

```
SELECT DISTINCT email 
FROM tresp 
WHERE email NOT IN ('[email addy here]','[email addy here]')
```

Comment: Thanks but neither of those give what I need.  I need to know from the list of email in the SQL statement, which of those are NOT in tresp - make sense?

Comment: You have a list of emails, you are querying tresp, you want to know which email addresses are in that list but are not in tresp?

Comment: @Simonatmso.net: Sounds like what he wants to me

Comment: @Homer_J: See [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273623/mysql-select-from-a-list-of-numbers-those-without-a-counterpart-in-the-id-fiel) for more info and options

Comment: @josh.trow - Hmm, just read that - I take it I need a temp table?

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but this may do what you wish, trying to find a more elegant solution but this at least works

```
SELECT 
    findTheseEmails.email
FROM
(
    SELECT CONVERT(_latin1 'test@foo.com' USING utf8) AS email
    UNION SELECT CONVERT(_latin1 'bar@fooo.com' USING utf8)
    UNION SELECT CONVERT(_latin1 'woww@foo.com' USING utf8)
    UNION SELECT CONVERT(_latin1 'teasfsafst@foo.com' USING utf8)
) AS findTheseEmails

LEFT JOIN tresp
ON tresp.email = findTheseEmails.email

WHERE tresp.email IS NULL
```

Comment: Error: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Comment: @Homer_J See the link in my answer for an answer to that problem.

Comment: @Homer_J adjusted the query - though personally I try and avoid mixing collations - would point @ something slightly amiss within your configuration

Comment: @Simonatmso.net: latin1_swedish_ci is the default collation for MySQL - that's what you get for having Swedish developers :)

Comment: @josh.trow Unfortunately I've had the pain of having to correct an old database schema from latin_1_swedish_ci to a more general collation during a migration.   The "fun" hasn't fled memory just yet.  Especially the ENUM fields.  Suffice to say, a script to automate the process was rather required :)