# Query returns null instead of 0

Tags: mysql

I have a query that counts all Work ID Numbers by month and year and then creates a chart for the past 13 months using jpgraph.  It works great except there are no Work ID Numbers in July so the chart totally skips July.

Query Results:

```
5
16
15
11
3
12
4
8
2
9
13
12
```

Desired Results:

```
5
16
15
11
3
12
0
4
8
2
9
13
12
```

As you can see I need the (0) zero in order for my chart to work, however since there are no Work ID Number in July my query simply skips it.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT( WORK_ID_NUM ) AS count, 
DATE FROM SERVICE_JOBS 
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '$lastyear' AND '$date') 
AND JOB_TYPE LIKE 'Street Light' 
GROUP BY YEAR( DATE ), MONTH( DATE )
 ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: So you're trying to select data that doesn't actually exist and you want it to be in the results :) You will have to first create that data and then left join it. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034668/how-to-generate-data-in-mysql)

Comment: As a side note, take into account that not returning a result is very different than returning `null` as you stated in your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273623/mysql-select-from-a-list-of-numbers-those-without-a-counterpart-in-the-id-fiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[sqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30e1c/25/2)</kbd>

```
SELECT IFNULL(count,0) as count,theDate as Date
FROM 
      (SELECT @month := @month+INTERVAL 1 MONTH as theDate
       FROM service_jobs,(SELECT @month:='$lastyear' - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)as T1
       LIMIT 13)as T2
LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT COUNT(WORK_ID_NUM)as count,DATE
       FROM service_jobs
       WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '$lastyear' AND '$date') 
         AND JOB_TYPE LIKE 'Street Light' 
       GROUP BY YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE)) T3
 ON (YEAR(theDate) = YEAR(DATE) AND MONTH(theDate) = MONTH(DATE))
ORDER BY theDate;
```

Comment: it works but it's a hack (assuming you always have more than 13 rows of data in service_jobs)

Comment: I am fine with a hack!  It works!  And yes there will always be a lot more than 13!  Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, but I don't know how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get your query to return a row for July, you need to have a row with July in it.  You could create a table with all the dates between $lastyear and $date in it and then outer join from that to SERVICE_JOB.

```
SELECT COUNT( WORK_ID_NUM ) AS count, 
       allDates.DATE 
FROM AllDates 
Left outer join SERVICE_JOB
on AllDates.DATE = SERVICE_JOB.DATE
WHERE (AllDates.DATE BETWEEN '$lastyear' AND '$date') AND
(SERVICE_JOB.WORK_ID_NUM is NULL OR JOB_TYPE LIKE 'Street Light')
GROUP BY YEAR( AllDates.DATE ), MONTH( AllDates.DATE ) 
ORDER BY AllDates.DATE
```

In SQL Server it would be pretty easy to make a Common Table Expression that could fill AllDates for you based on $lastyear and $date.  Not sure about MySql.

Comment: I did that and the results in 0 rows ...  I created my AllDates table as follows: ID | DATE and then I have an integer as the ID and 2012-12-01 - 2014-01-01 as the date range.  What have I done wrong?  Thanks!